# How to read a JSON file stored in Firebase Storage with NextJS in a web app?

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase `v9.6.2` in a NextJS project. I would need to read JSON files from Firebase Storage. I've created a Flutter App that does that, and this app stores files in Storage, and now I need to read these files from a web project.

I have a simple page in which I implement the following function:

```js
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const revalidate = 3;
  const storage = getStorage();
  const dataPath = "data/";
  const reference = ref(storage, dataPath);
  const listResult = await listAll(reference);
  let listOfFiles = [];
  for (let item of listResult.items) {
    if (item.name.endsWith(".json")) {
      await storage
        .getDownloadURL(skillsPath + item.name)
        .then(async (url) => {
          let content = await fetch(url, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
          });
          // the error happens before this line so I comment it out:
          // content = await content.json();
          listOfFiles.push(content);
        })
    }
  }

  console.log(listOfFiles);

  return { props: { listOfFiles }, revalidate };
}
```

`listOfFiles` is this:

```
[
  Response {
    size: 0,
    timeout: 0,
    [Symbol(Body internals)]: { body: [PassThrough], disturbed: false, error: null },
    [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
      url: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blablablabla...',
      status: 403,
      statusText: 'Forbidden',
      headers: [Headers],
      counter: 0
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

Notes:

- The issue does not come from the rules
- The user is authenticated
- I have enabled Firebase Storage and there are my files, I get the correct URL.

Basically it looks like the example on the official documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url), however it does not work with NextJS (with XMLHttpRequest either: `XMLHttpRequest is not defined`).

If this problem is too complicated, or impossible, maybe I can use Firestore instead, however my JSON files are pretty big and I don't know if there is a limitation on the size of the data's keys.

I hope this is clear, please tell me if not.

Comment: The 403 status code indicates the request is not authorised. `getStaticProps` runs on the server at build time, it doesn't have access to user-related data.

Comment: Then I can't access the content of files within `getStaticProps` ? Is there a way to do that with Firebase ?